# Unable to connect iPhone with xcode

Tags: xcode14, xcode14.3

When i connect my iPhone to xcode i am getting this error

> Can't make device ready for development: The developer disk image could not be mounted on this device.

and in the details i see this

> Error mounting image: 0xe8000106 (kAMDMobileImageMounterCredentialsFailed: AppleConnect authentication failed or was cancelled.

Details

```
Can't make device ready for development: The developer disk image could not be mounted on this device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTCoreDevice
Code: -19
Failure Reason: Error mounting image: 0xe8000106 (kAMDMobileImageMounterCredentialsFailed: AppleConnect authentication failed or was cancelled.)
User Info: {
    DDIPath = "/Users/br/Library/Developer/DeveloperDiskImages/iOS_DDI.dmg";
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-04-07 07:36:29 +0000";
    "com.apple.dt.DVTCoreDevice.operationName" = enablePersonalizedDDI;
```

i have restarted mac and iphone many times and already removed and re downloaded the xcode version 14.3

Comment: Did u turn on Dev mode? iPhone Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Mode.

Comment: yes Dev mode is turned on

Comment: Well maybe your phone cannot open this project/app because your Apple account in iPhone doesn't have permission?

Comment: Can you please explain. The apple account i am using in iphone is the admin of the apple developer account i am using for the app

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the xcode junk and it started working. I mostly use cleanmymac app to clean mac from extra junk files

Comment: what's xcode junk

Comment: temp files or files which are not needed but still there on disk. cache files etc

Comment: restarting phone did the trick